# document.activeElement is empty when listening to beforeunload

Tags: javascript, listener, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to get the last active element before unloading the document through the `beforeunload` window listener.

I'm doing it this way:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {    
    localStorage.setItem('activeElement',document.activeElement);   
  });
```

The item `activeElement` contains only an empty object. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Because you can't stringify an element. You will need to get details of that element and store them instead. What is your actual use case?

Comment: @charlietfl even without stringyfying it, it remains blank. 
I'm creating a script running on web pages that sets the last active item before unloading in local storage.

Comment: localStorage only accepts strings, you can't store a whole element either

Comment: @charlietfl even when I console log it, it logs a blank line.

Comment: Again, you will need to extract details of the element using Element interface methods & getters. As for use case what do you plan to do with it when you retrieve it from storage?

Comment: What is triggering the unloading of the current document here in your situation?